# Display parallel child elements in a same row in single table by angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, parent-child

My JSON format:

```
[
 {  
  'name': 'George',
  'age': '44',
  'children': [
     {
       'name': 'Jack',
       'age': 16,
     },
     {
       'name' : 'Amy',
       'age': 13
     } ],
  'nephew' : [
     {
       'name':'jj',
       'age':11
     }, 
     {
       'name':'kk', 
       'age':12 
     } ]
 }, 
 {
    'name': 'Jimmy',
    'age': 38,
    'children': [
        {
          'name': 'Max',
          'age': 7              
        },
        {
          'name': 'Lily',
          'age': 5
        } ],
    'nephew' : [
        {
          'name':'xx',
          'age':41
        }, 
        { 
          'name':'yy', 
          'age':42 
        } ] 
 }
];
```

In table-1, i displayed george,44 in 1st TR and jimmy,38 in 2nd TR. Then i need to display in table-2 which should contain: CHILDREN's data and NEPHEW's data in single row. That is jack,16, Amy, 13, jj, 11, kk, 12 all in 1st ROW. So in 2nd ROW i need to display jimmy's children and nephew.

I just got the code to display one child's element(CHILDREN) like "x in person.children", but cannot achieve parallel child's element(NEPHEW) that too in single ROW.

Please provide your ideas.

RE-EDIT: updated json format:

```
[
 {
 'name': 'George',
 'age': '44',
 'children': [
    {
        'name': 'Jack',
        'age': 'jack-16',
        'month': 'jack-june'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Amy',
        'age': 'amy-13',
        'month': 'amy-jan'
    }],
 'nephew': [
    {
        'name': 'jj',
        'age': 'jj-11',
        'year': 'jj-2000'
    },
    {
        'name': 'kk',
        'age': 'kk-12',
        'year': 'kk-1995'
    }]
  },
 {
 'name': 'Jimmy',
 'age': 38,
 'children': [
     {
         'name': 'Max',
         'age': 'max-7',
         'month': 'max-nov'
     },
     {
         'name': 'Lily',
         'age': 'lily-5',
         'month': 'lily-dec'
     }],
 'nephew': [
     {
         'name': 'xx',
         'age': 'xx-41',
         'year': 'xx-2005'
     },
     {
         'name': 'yy',
         'age': 'yy-42',
         'year': 'yy-2003'
     }]
  }
 ];
```

I need table-1 and table-2 to display data like in this:

[image].

I believe only custom filter can achieve this format, but I can't make it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your controller:

```
    $scope.people =  [
 {
     'name': 'George',
     'age': '44',
     'children': [
        {
            'name': 'Jack',
            'age': 16,
        },
        {
            'name': 'Amy',
            'age': 13
        }],
     'nephew': [
        {
            'name': 'jj',
            'age': 11
        },
        {
            'name': 'kk',
            'age': 12
        }]
 },
 {
     'name': 'Jimmy',
     'age': 38,
     'children': [
         {
             'name': 'Max',
             'age': 7
         },
         {
             'name': 'Lily',
             'age': 5
         }],
     'nephew': [
         {
             'name': 'xx',
             'age': 41
         },
         {
             'name': 'yy',
             'age': 42
         }]
 }
    ];
```

In your HTML:

```
    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in people">
        <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in people">
        <td ng-repeat="c in p.children">{{c.name}}</td><td ng-repeat="n in p.nephew">{{n.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> Here's an update for your table

```
    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in people">
        <td>{{p.name}}</td><td>{{p.age}}</td><td> <table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="c in p.children">{{c.name}}</th><th ng-repeat="n in p.nephew">{{n.name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> <td  ng-repeat="c in p.children"><span>{{c.age}}</span><span>{{c.month}}</span></td> <td ng-repeat="n in p.nephew"><span>{{n.age}}</span><span>{{n.month}}</span></td></tr>
</table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I also updated the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dPyoCsW23O1FPE78W2rI?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But i didn't update my json proper and right requirement. Please check my re-edited json and table structure in image and see if you can help. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I already tried this table tag inside a TD tag. It achieved my format, but its not right solution when i use huge data. Also i'm using table structure, pagination where i would re-use each row from two tables again. span tags are not applicable here. I prefer to use custom filter to accomplish this formatted table. Please let me know if you achieve this using **filter**.